# Scope of implicit functions in objects with the same name as the class in scala

Tags: scala, scope, implicit-conversion

The question is simple: in Scala, are the implicit function definitions of object A in the scope of class A? Or do I have to explicitly use `import A._` to get access to the implicit functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is simple: in Scala, are the implicit function definitions of object A in the scope of class A?

No, you have to import them (same as non-implicit members of `object A`). But of course, any implicit conversions *from or to `A`* are always searched in the companion object, if there are none in scope.